# Sailsjs file upload is not working

Tags: node.js, file-upload, sails.js

I am trying to implement file upload api in sailsjs ([Followed this](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/file-uploads)), but the DeprecationWarning is showing while dealing with file type.

```
(node:23566) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
```

Sailsjs version: 0.12.14

I have solved the deprecated warning by changing the 55th line in 
node_modules/sails/node_modules/skipper/node_modules/multiparty/index.js

from
  self.uploadDir = options.uploadDir || os.tmpDir();
to
  self.uploadDir = options.uploadDir || os.tmpdir();

But still the files is not getting in the request.

The request.file('avatar') is as shown below: where avatar is the form field name of file type.

```
Upstream {
  _fatalErrors: [],
  isNoop: true,
  _files: [],
  timeouts: 
   { untilFirstFileTimer: 
      Timeout {
        _called: false,
        _idleTimeout: 10000,
        _idlePrev: [TimersList],
        _idleNext: [TimersList],
        _idleStart: 3295,
        _onTimeout: [Function],
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: null,
        _destroyed: false,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 302,
        [Symbol(triggerAsyncId)]: 289 },
     untilMaxBufferTimer: 
      Timeout {
        _called: false,
        _idleTimeout: 4500,
        _idlePrev: [TimersList],
        _idleNext: [TimersList],
        _idleStart: 3295,
        _onTimeout: [Function],
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: null,
        _destroyed: false,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 304,
        [Symbol(triggerAsyncId)]: 289 } },
  _readableState: 
   ReadableState {
     objectMode: true,
     highWaterMark: 16,
     buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: null,
     ended: false,
     endEmitted: false,
     reading: false,
     sync: true,
     needReadable: false,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     resumeScheduled: false,
     destroyed: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: false,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: true,
  domain: null,
  _events: {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  fieldName: 'NOOP_avatar' }
------------
events.js:137
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: EMAXBUFFER: An Upstream (`NOOP_avatar`) timed out before it was plugged into a receiver. It was still unused after waiting 4500ms. You can configure this timeout by changing the `maxTimeToBuffer` option.
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/skipper/standalone/Upstream/Upstream.js:86:15)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:458:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:296:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:259:5)
```

Comment: What does the upload form look like?

Comment: Now I am trying from the postman where I have used the post method and used the header: Content-Type as multipart/form-data

Comment: Try removing the content header, postman should do this itself.

Comment: No hassle, its something I've faced a few times :)

Comment: But how can we solve the  DeprecationWarning problem?
The solution which I have used is not a best practice as we are not pushing out node_modules to git or production servers as the package.json file exists.

Comment: I think the deprecation warning is more to do with the version of Node.js you are using rather that Sails.

Comment: But I am using the stable version of nodejs and sailsjs which should supposed to be working rt?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165839/discussion-between-glen-and-sanjay-kumar-n-s).